# Rails 3.1 - changing default scaffold views and template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, view, haml, scaffolding

I'm using rails 3.1 with Zune Foundation templates and haml.  I have tried to fiend ways to change the default scaffold view templates to use css I want so I get a consistent look with all scaffold without manually changing the view.  I also use simple_form.

As I don't want to program my own generators, is there some easy and/or recommended ways to handle this?

Johann

Comment: The typical recommendation is to not use scaffolds for views you intent to publish, and to just do them manually.

Answer (score 33):

You can override default view templates by creating your own templates in 'lib/templates/erb/scaffold' folder of your rails app.

```
  lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.html.erb
  lib/templates/erb/scaffold/edit.html.erb
  lib/templates/erb/scaffold/index.html.erb
  lib/templates/erb/scaffold/new.html.erb
  lib/templates/erb/scaffold/show.html.erb
```

The default templates can be found here - https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates

Comment: Hey for haml how to us?

Comment: I just did this for haml... same process just replace erb for haml and got the original templates from https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/haml/scaffold/templates