# Easy way to cusomize views of Rails' scaffold generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scaffolding, ruby-on-rails-4

I know how to [create a new generator in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html). However, I simply want to tweak the views a bit. Is there an easy way to do this? I guess I could go into the directory in my operating system where Rails resides and modify those files (I assume that's easy). But then those changes will apply to every Rails project, not just the one I care about at the moment. And it'll get wiped away when I update Rails (frequently).

Using Rails 3.2.13, but happy to upgrade to 4.0 beta if that helps.

Comment: I looked through a few pages of docs and couldn't find anything. Good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer in [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3?view=asciicast), note particularly the section on "Customizing Templates". You create the files in your Rails root `lib/` directory, so it won't apply to every app, just your current one, and it will be independent of Rails versions.

Comment: I watched the entire RailsCast only to find out that Ryan couldn't get it to work... Found this answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688220/rails-3-1-changing-default-scaffold-views-and-template

Comment: Oops; I should have pointed out that I hadn't tried it myself. That said, the ASCIICast version looks like it has the same answer as that stackoverflow question (unless I'm missing some nuance).