# Rails modify scaffold to use simple_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to modify rails scaffold command to generate forms using `simple_form` gem input fields?, instead of having the developer to edit each form and convert it to use `simple_form`  data fields?

PS: I did Google and search Stack Overflow before posting, all I found was how to modify existing scaffold, which is not what I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can override the templates used for generated views by putting templates here:

lib/templates/erb/scaffold

take a look at:

[Rails 3.1 - changing default scaffold views and template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688220/rails-3-1-changing-default-scaffold-views-and-template)